# Jmeter: Using  " N " number of Web service request in same thread group. 

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter 2.4.

In that I'm trying to use "N" number of WebService (SOAP) Request Sampler in a single Thread Group. But in all that "N" Number WebService (SOAP) Request, the WSDL URL is `http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?WSDL` is same. Tested webservice has 4 methods. So i need to check all 4 methods, by using 4 different WebService(SOAP) Requests in order to check each method in each request.

**Problem is:**
If i choose one method in 1st WebService(SOAP) Request, then in the remaining other 3 WebService(SOAP) Request, the method get changed automatically to same as the one that i have chosen in 1st WebService(SOAP) Request.

**Expected as:**
I want to choose other 3 methods in other 3 WebService (SOAP) Request respectively. So that, i can test webservice request for all the 4 methods in 4 different WebService (SOAP) Request.

Hope, if any clarification regarding my question, I'm ready to explain in more.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any one to reply for my question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Struggling for one week. I had found solution for my Question. yes, It is possible to make "N" number of Web Service request in Jmeter. It is as like using "N" number of Http request, by using "N" number of Http WebService Request Sampler and configure them.